# Full screen carousel css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a carousel using CSS, but I want the image to not distort when enlarged and still take up most of the screen. I made a little code showing my problem.

```
div.some{
    width: 1400px;
    height: 900px;   
    background-color: red;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="some">
        <img src="IMG_7331.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

And this is what happen if i use, background-size, or object-fit.

```
div.some{
    width: 1400px;
    height: 900px;   
    background-color: red;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

[image]

How can you see, the image is cropped, how can I keep the image without distortion, if I modify the height and make it smaller or a maximum, just like the image below.

However I would like to do something like this:
[image]

How can I see the image occupies the whole screen and when modifying its height it is not distorted, how can I do this?

Comment: Might be better to use background images that cover the elements, or perhaps object-fit

Comment: How should the image's size be defined, by the page's width or height? To keep the same proportions, just set the width of the image to the width of the page without setting maximum height.

Comment: @PhixI tried both but the image is cropped, I will edit the post and show you.

Comment: @showdev in this case it is necessary because I want the image to always have a high maximum.

Comment: What should happen when the image has a different aspect ratio than its container? Should it be cropped or letterboxed?

Comment: @showdev I understand, now the question is, can I modify the aspect ratio of an image? Is there a program? Or does it just keep its aspect ratio based on the device that took the photo?

Comment: You can crop the image in photo editing software, crop it programmatically, or just hide part of the image that doesn't fit. What I meant was: how specifically do you want it to behave?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS `object-fit` property. So in your case, the CSS would like this:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Furthermore you can use the object-position property to specify the alignment of the image. It defaults to the center (50% 50%).

Read more on [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and [object-postion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position).

Comment: I tried this, but the problem with this is that it crops the image, let's say 30% of the image does not appear, i will edit the post and i show u.

Comment: @brayanmilian thats because the image you are using has a different aspect ratio than the space you are trying to fill (1400px x 500px). its like trying to fit a square block into a rectangle slot - they have different ratios. You also have to consider different screen sizes and browser widths... you have to compromise, usually by cropping out part of the img that doesnt fit

Comment: @brayanmilian You can't expect to maintain the current aspect ratio of the image if you want it to span to a 100%, width and height of the viewport. If you want you can align the image on the x or y axis using object-position property.

Comment: @brayanmilian If you don't want the image cropped, you can try `object-fit: contain` and it will be letterboxed instead.

Comment: @showdev if you `object-fit: contain;` it will not take the full height and width of parent/ viewport, as it simply scales the image to maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: @zgood I understand, now the question is, can I modify the aspect ratio of an image? Is there a program? Or does it just keep its aspect ratio based on the device that took the photo? If I modify the aspect ratio of the image it could probably solve the problem of the image cropping?

Comment: @nadz I got it dude, now can i modify the aspect ratio of an image? If I modify the aspect ratio of the image it could probably solve the problem of the image cropping?

Comment: @brayanmilian you can use something like photoshop to crop your image to 1400px x 500px but you will still be cropping it (the same the object-fit is doing). If you are modifying the aspect ratio you are either cropping it or skewing/streching (distorting) the image. Those are your only options

Comment: @zgood I understand, but then based on the "mercado libre" image, what is the treatment given to this image, assuming that the aspect ratio is according to its container, because in this case the image is not cropped

Comment: @brayanmilian If you're really worried about the image being cropped I'd fix one of the axis's so the image will scale. Or you can try adding some padding to the image using a photo editing software like Photoshop.

Comment: @brayanmilian I can't tell from your screenshot, but I assume the example is image is the correct aspect ratio for its container, and the image you are using is not. No special treatment, just different images. Whats the dimensions of the image you are trying to use for this 1400 x 500 container?

Comment: @zgood The original size of the image is around 6000 x 5000 (approximately), I used a program (different from photoshop), and changed the image dimension to 1400 x 200, with this I have managed to avoid cropping. Cadcisious question, I imagine that it is not possible to make the image less narrow due to the dimensions (1400x200), based on that because my image is stretched so much and the "mercado libre" image does not, assuming now that my aspect ratio is fine.Now I assume it is because of the form and content of the image as such.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you use high-resolution asset images for the maximum (wanted) screen size(device-width)
- Use css `background-size` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

- For best practice, add value to the`alt` attribute

Comment: I tried this, but the problem with this is that it crops the image, let's say 30% of the image does not appear, i will edit the post and i show u.

Comment: Background-size property only works if your image is set as a background image not for img tags.